# Silverlight Plug-In in Safari 12

Tags: safari, plugins, silverlight

is there any way to enable the Silverlight Plug-In in Safari 12? I need this plug in to watch a live sport event.

Thanks!

Comment: I would remove the version that is currently installed and then go to microsoft.com/silverlight and install the latest version. If that does not work then MS needs to update Silverlight to work with the new browser. Nothing you can do except use a different browser in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there any way to enable the Silverlight Plug-In in Safari 12?

No, there is no way to make the current version of the Silverlight plugin work with Safari 12.

As of today, **no actively supported web browser on macOS can run the current Silverlight plugin** (neither Safari, Chrome nor Firefox, see below for more information). The culprit is the technology the plugin is based on: [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI), which has been deprecated in all major browsers because of security concerns, the latest of them being Safari with version 12.

This means that you must use an unsupported browser, with all the risks that entails.

If you insist on using Silverlight on macOS, I think your "safest" bet would be **Firefox 52 ESR** for that specific sports site. You can download it from [Mozilla's release repository](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.9.0esr/).

Firefox 52 ESR has been replaced with [Firefox 60 ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/), but its latest version is somewhat recent, released on June 25 2018.

As explained above, neither [Safari 12](https://developer.apple.com/safari/whats-new/), [Chrome version 45 or later](https://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html) nor [Firefox 52 or later](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/npapi-plugins) support NPAPI plugins, with the exception of Adobe Flash.

Comment: "with the exception of Adobe Flash." So the code to support NPAPI plugins is there, the browsers are just artificially restricting installation of anything other than Flash. >:(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. A long time ago I used a Browser from Germany called iCab.

I installed the newest iCab version 5.85.5. It cost $10 USD and it works fine with Silverlight on macOS 10.13.6.

Comment: Webadress: www.icab.de

Answer (score 3):

I make it work on Mac Mojave

First i uninstall silverlight like is on this site:

Way 1 – Uninstall Silverlight Manually

https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-silverlight-on-mac

I did use the app Funter (free)
Then i install silverlight again
And install seamonkey browser (free)

https://www.seamonkey-project.org/

Then i go to finder, applications i click with the right click of the mouse, get info, and select the option app nap.
And it start to work on seamonkey browser

Comment: works fine on mac Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Google Chrome is running Netflix just fine on my mac. (mid 2010 mini, 10.13.6 High Sierra)

That's the only work around I know for older macs, according to Netflix newer macs will show video in html5.

Reference: https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742

- Safari on Mac OS X 10.10 or later (Yosemite)
- Supported on all 2012 or later models and select 2011 models

Comment: The original question doesn't seem to be asking about Netflix, since they said they were trying to watch a live sporting event. With that being said, you're looking at the requirements for the HTML5 player instead of Silverlight, which likely explains why it's working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Install icab browser on mac and it work fine [For Downloadin SIlverlight based application](http://www.icab.de)

If you have upgraded you safari browser to 12.0 then you cant download silverlight based application you have to download this ICab Browser

Answer (score -3):

Opera browser works just fine as well.

Answer (score -4):

I got the browser SeaMonkey and Microsoft Silverlight 5 worked on there.