# Safari won't play Amazon Prime Video on my iMac?

Tags: macos, safari, video

If I try to play videos on my iMac using Safari it won't play, but it plays fine using Chrome. I'm using macOS High Sierra and I'm running Safari version 12.1.

When I try using Safari I get a black screen with a message as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get Safari to play videos?

I don't think I had Silverlight installed but I don't know how to tell. I went ahead and installed version 5.1 of Silverlight but again I can't tell if its installed. When I go to Safari preferences and click on security I get the pane shown below.

[image]

Comment: What version of Safari?  Version of macOS?  Have you seen [Prime Video System Requirements](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201422810)?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check your [Silverlight plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) and confirm that it's installed and working properly. According to their website titled: [Prime Video System Requirements for Computers](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201422810), these are the versions supported:

- Mac OS 10.7 or newer
- Safari (version 10 or newer on Mac OS 10.12.1 or newer)
- The minimum supported version of Silverlight is 5.1

If you have the correct versions then make sure that the Silverlight plugin is enabled and configured properly in Safari, as shown below.

[image: ss#1]

[image: ss#2]

**NOTE:** You can navigate to HDD → Library → Internet Plug-ins to verify that Silverlight is installed.

[image: ss3]

#### Safari 12 and Amazon Prime

Curiously if I merely navigate to Prime Videos I'm able to play videos without any additional plugins using their built-in HTML5 player.

[image: ss4]

Additional research turned up this other AD Q&A titled: [Silverlight Plug-In in Safari 12](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336838/silverlight-plug-in-in-safari-12) which indicated that Silverlight was no longer supported in Safari 12.

#### References

- [Amazon Prime Video & Safari: Let's Call a Truce](http://macithelp.blogspot.com/2016/05/amazon-prime-video-safari-lets-call.html)

Comment: Good questions / discussion - [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92172/discussion-on-answer-by-slm-safari-wont-play-amazon-prime-video-on-my-imac).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem... I got the "missing plug-in" message too when I tried to play an Amazon Prime movie on my 2009 Imac with Safari Version 11.1.2 and El Capitan 10.11.6.

My solution was to drop Safari Browser and go to Google Chrome (Version 88.0.4324.192) and I got immediate access to the Amazon Prime movie (Minari). I enjoyed this great movie on my 24 inch iMac screen.